# Strange drop in transmission speed over TCP/IP

Tags: tcp

Disclaimer: I'm a software dev so this low level stuff isn't my area of expertise! I hope I'm on the right Stack Exchange site for this question.

I'm developing a Windows application that communicates with a hardware device via TCP/IP. The device is an FPGA board which I believe runs Linux. Interaction involves the PC sending a small "request" message to the device, which responds with a block of data, approx 32kb in length.

So far I've written a very basic PC client to test the comms. I click a button which sends a request to the FPGA then reads the response back. This entire process (from clicking the button to receiving the entire 32kb response) typically takes around 2-3ms. I can keep clicking the button every second or two and the timings will remain at this level.

However I've found that if I start clicking the button a little quicker (a couple of times a second) then after a few seconds this time will drop to around 12ms. It will remain at this level even if I then slow down my button clicking. If I disconnect/reconnect the client* then try again, timings are back to the 2-3ms level. (* I just close the connection then reconnect, I don't actually restart the application).

I'm as confident as I can be that it's not the software on the PC or FPGA, both of which are really very simple. Gut feeling is that it's something "protocoly"? Below are Wireshark screenshots showing traces from a "fast" response, and one from when it has dropped to 12ms. Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question involving software development are off-topic here. You can ask this on [so] where there are many network-savvy programmers.

Comment: One possible "protocoly" explanation is that the acks are handled differently during light traffic vs heavy traffic, affecting the TCP window size and delay between packets.  There are ways to use wireshark to watch this specific trait.  Hansang Bae has a number of great talks covering the ins and outs of this, here is one: http://www.youtube.com/embed/qvDmdv1-Xik

Comment: @JeffMeden will take a look, thanks. Have now posted on SO as suggested, for a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

Going to thrown a partial answer out there.  The packet trace shows that from when the ack is sent by your PC to your FPGA, about 1ms elapses until the FPGA starts sending more traffic.  The first example shows the FPGA putting lots more bytes "in flight" (sent before an ack) which means the ACK delay penalty was only seen twice.  The second example shows an ack after every 2 packets, and then a 1ms delay.  This adds up quickly so that at the end of the 32kb transmission, the 10 extra acks slow it down by about 10ms.  Why the FPGA is waiting for acks more frequently is unclear, but if it's Linux based there are ways of controlling the window size, scaling, and acking in the kernel that you should probably try in order to have more deterministic behavior (the defaults often try to automatically adjust to network conditions by watching things like delays, buffer capacity, dropped packets, etc).  If you suspect the PC is at fault for some reason you can control the behavior in windows via specific registry keys.  One other thing to look at is the use/effect of Nagle's algorithm by the host/client.